# Replace white space with AND in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have someone entering a form with some string input.  What I need to do is replace any white space in the string with " AND " (no quotes).  What's the best way to do this?

Also, how would I go about doing this if I wanted to remove all the whitespace in the string?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to replace with and:

```
s = 'this has   some     whitespace'
s.gsub! /\s+/, ' AND '

=> "this AND has AND some AND whitespace"
```

to remove altogether:

```
s = 'this has   some     whitespace'
s.gsub! /\s+/, ''

=> "thishassomewhitespace"
```

Comment: How would you check to see if the string has white space already in it?

Answer (score 4):

Split and join is another technique:

```
s = "   a   b   c   "
s.split(' ').join(' AND ')
# => "a AND b AND c"
```

This has the advantage of ignoring leading and trailing whitespace that Peter's RE does not:

```
s = "   a   b   c   "
s.gsub /\s+/, ' AND '
# => " AND a AND b AND c AND "
```

Removing whitespace

```
s.split(' ').join('')
# or
s.delete(' ')  # only deletes space chars
```

Answer (score 1):

use gsub method for replacing whitespace

```
 s = "ajeet soni"

 => "ajeet soni" 

 s.gsub(" "," AND ")

 => "ajeet AND soni"
```